# Is it possible with jquery to use the nth-child() selector on an 'a' or an 'a:hover', not just 'li'?

Tags: jquery-selectors

Ive created a navigation bar where the hover state of each link has be a different color so im trying to select the a:hover states with jquerys nth-child() selector. i can get it to select the li element but not the a or the a:hover. Currently all the hovers are blue.

here is the jquery code im trying to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
jQuery('#leftbar li:nth-child(3)').css('border-bottom', '#000000 5px solid');
});
```

Hi the navigation is generated with php, here it is:

```
<ul id="leftbar">
<?php
$pagepath = "content/pages/";
$legalpath = "content/legals/";

$mainnavpath = "content/.system-use/navigation/";
$mainnavfile =  $mainnavpath."mainnav.inc";
if (file_exists($mainnavfile)) {
require $mainnavfile;


sort ($mainfiles);


for($i=0; $i<count($mainfiles); $i++)
{
if (!preg_match("/XX-/",$mainfiles[$i])) {
$displayname = preg_replace("/\.inc/i", "", $mainfiles[$i]);
$displayname = substr($displayname, 3);
echo "<li>";

echo "<a ";
if ($page==$displayname) {echo ' class="active"';} else {echo ' class="prinav"';}


echo "title='$displayname' href='";
if ($useredirect=="yes"){echo '/'.$displayname.'/';} else {echo  '/index.php?page='.$displayname;}
echo"' ";
echo "><span>$displayname</span></a></li>\n";

}}
}

else { echo "<strong>No Navigation - Please Login to your Admin System and set the Page Order</strong>"; }
?>
```

here is the site im working on:
http://entourageuk.com/

Cheers!
Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, would be nice if you post the html part! tnx.

Comment: Hi i have edited the post to include the html which is created with php

Answer (score 1):

You can't select using a CSS pseudo selector like `:hover`, but yes, you can select an `<a>` element.

Whether `:nth-child` is appropriate depends on your markup. I'm going to assume that each `<a>` is a child of the `<li>` elements you're selecting.

If that's the case, then you would just add `a` to the selector.

```
jQuery('#leftbar li:nth-child(3) > a').css(...
```

This uses [the `>` child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), and is basically saying that I want the `<a>` element(s) that is a direct child of the `<li>` element(s) that is the third child of its container and is a descendant of `leftbar`.